# Unable to get Access Token in Jmeter

Tags: rest, api, oauth, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to get an access token in Jmeter, and it works fine with postman, but I end up with an error in response in Jmeter saying

```
{
   "error":"invalid_grant",
   "error_description":"The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client",
   "status_code":400
}
```

Postman Body
[image]

Header in postman
[image]

I get access token as json response when i post this request

My setup in Jmeter looks as follows:

HTTP request
[image]

HTTP Header 
[image]

I get following response when i run the test in jmeter

```
{
   "error":"invalid_grant",
   "error_description":"The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client",
   "status_code":400
}
```

Comment: Please provide jmeter log. To get or extract access token you should be using Json extractor or xpath extractor.

Answer (score 0):

Given you send the same requests you should be getting the same responses so most probably the requests differ somewhere somehow.

You need to compare [raw request body from Postman](https://blog.postman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/) and the same from JMeter using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

One obvious difference is missing [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header in JMeter.

It might be the case that variables like `${_code}` and `${base64HeaderValue}` don't have their respective values, you might want to check them using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

And last but not the least, if your request works in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-)

[image]

And next time you run the request in Posman JMeter will capture it and store the relevant HTTP Request sampler (with the HTTP Header Manager) under the Recording Controller